# Fetch request failing (laravel)

Tags: laravel, reactjs

I am using the following `fetch` to make a `POST` request...

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://laravel.dev/content', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({

        })
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
    });
}
```

But the request is failing. I get the following error...

```
POST http://laravel.dev/content 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

My `route` in `routes.php` looks like...

```
Route::post('/content', 'Test@save');
```

I checked my `laravel.dev/content` and the following error message appears, I am not sure if it is normal...

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

Any reason why my request is failing.

Comment: Do you have the content route inside a group?

Comment: @YohananBaruchel no its only that route alone in my `routes.php`

Comment: Have you tried Route::post('content', 'Test@save'); ?

Comment: @YohananBaruchel I just did, still get the same error

Comment: Yet again, this is problem of SERVER not Laravel or PHP, please consult your SERVER logs (apache or nginx), and the problem is in permissions; `/storage` is not writeable by SERVER. And do not forget delete this mess of a question asked million times.

Comment: Yeah that error in your log would actually return as a 404 error so it probably wasn't generated with your `/content` request but with something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you actually have a controller for this? If not, you need to create one:

```
    class Test extends Controller
    {

       public function save()
       {
          ...
       }

    }
```

You also need to make sure that you are sending the csrf token with the request. Add the following to your blade template view form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
```

Comment: Yes I have the controller but still getting this issue.

Comment: Then you need to do some fault finding. What happens if you try to post to the route using a normal html form rather than js? This will tell you where the problem is - either in your route or your js.

Comment: Are you sending the csrf token with the post request? See updated answer

Comment: ok I submitted the form, and it works fine. No errors. The issue is only when I make the fetch request I get an error. If I remove "mode:no-cors" I get a preflighted error, and when I add it I get 500 internal server error...would it help to make a repo? (Note both my front-end and the laravel restAPI are hosted on XAMPP)